# LinearRegression ploting with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

https://www.kaggle.com/paree24/development-index
i am trying to get my LinearRegression line but it doesnt show it right, any ideas?
also if i remove:

```
 plt.scatter(x_test**[:,0]**, y_test)
```

i get a warning *ValueError: x and y must be the same size*
there is another question regarding the graph, since the population column is in the billions, all the other figures (has shown in the picture below) are going to be close of equal to 0, can i fix this?
and also.... right now i have 3 different pictures showing my graphs in the beggining (because the same problem, the population column is too big)

```
plot1 = dataset.plot(x= "GDP ($ per capita)", y='Infant mortality ', style='o')
plot2 = dataset.plot(x= "Literacy (%)", y='Infant mortality ', style='o')
plot3 = dataset.plot(x= "Population", y='Infant mortality ', style='o')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

is there any way i can show these graphs in 1 picture and not in 3 different pictures?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from scipy.stats import shapiro
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
from math import sqrt
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
import seaborn as sns



dataset = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\coolh\Desktop\machine learning\lab1\Development.csv")


x = np.array(dataset.drop(columns= ["Area (sq. mi.)", "Pop. Density ", "Development Index", "Infant mortality "]))
y = np.array(dataset["Infant mortality "])


plot1 = dataset.plot(x= "GDP ($ per capita)", y='Infant mortality ', style='o')
plot2 = dataset.plot(x= "Literacy (%)", y='Infant mortality ', style='o')
plot3 = dataset.plot(x= "Population", y='Infant mortality ', style='o')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()


stat, p = shapiro(y)
print(f"показатель {p}")
print(f"статистика {stat}")


x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=10)
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(x_train, y_train)
print(f"regressor.intercept_ {regressor.intercept_}")
print(f"regressor.coef_{regressor.coef_}")


scores = cross_val_score(regressor, x, y, cv=5)
print(scores)
print("%0.2f accuracy with a standard deviation of %0.2f" % (scores.mean(), scores.std())) 


y_pred = regressor.predict(x_test)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Actual': y_test.flatten(), 'Predicted': y_pred.flatten()})



df1 = df.head(50)
df1.plot(kind = 'bar')
plt.grid(which ='major', color='green')
plt.grid(which='minor', color='red')
plt.show()


#RMSE
print(sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)))


plt.scatter(x_test[:,0], y_test)
plt.plot(x_test, y_pred, color='green', linewidth=1)
plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fbjxj.png)

Answer (score 0):

The `plot` method accepts the `ax` keyword that lets you plot onto an existing figure.  See the example below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({**{"x": range(10)}, **{f"y{i}": np.random.normal(size=10) for i in range(5)}})

fig = plt.figure()
df.plot("x", "y0", ax=plt.gca())
df.plot("x", "y1", ax=plt.gca())
df.plot("x", "y2", ax=plt.gca())
plt.show()
```

Note: since you're new, a piece of advice that has served me well is to include a MWE.  The code you posted is quite long and most of it is unrelated to the problem.